# Get first and last class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Might be a newbie question. I have a code line like this:

```
<div class="template active">
```

I need to get each class for itself.

**I tried this code:**

```
$(this).attr("class");
```

From that code I get "template active". What I need is one string with "template" and another with "active".

What is the best jQuery function for that? Example?

Comment: try this...$(this).attr("class").split(" ");

Comment: Many have been suggesting that and it works. Thanks, vote up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s/);

classes[0] === 'template'
classes[1] === 'active'
```

If there are more than two classnames and you only want to get the first & last (that was your question) you can call:

```
classes[0] = first class
classes[classes.length -1] = last class
```

Comment: What is the difference between .split(/\s/) and just .split(" ")?

Comment: @Jens: `/\s/` matches all possible white-space characters, not only space.

Answer (score 7):

```
var class= $(this).attr("class").split(" ").pop();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Javascript [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method:

```
var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're checking to see if a HTML element has a class, you can use .hasClass('classname') which would return true or false.

Otherwise, if you're trying to see a list,  I think you'll have split the string into an array.   The other two answers that were just posted will show you how.  :)

Comment: I tried hasClass but it did not work in my case. Works good in other cases. I give you a vote up anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
var class= $(this).attr("class").split(" ")  
(for i in class)
{ alert(class[i])}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eucm2/EcV4x/) is the easy way.

```
$(".element").last().addClass("highlight");
```

Comment: I think this would add a class of "highlight" to the last element. The original poster seems to want to access the last class name, rather than the last element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way too using `map`:-

```
var ArrayData = $.map($(this).attr("class").split(' '), function(value){
    return value;
});

alert("first class = '"+ArrayData[0]+"'");
alert("last class = '"+ArrayData[ArrayData.length - 1]+"'");
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/adDNz/)**