# jQuery: Remove and Re-Add Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

*I've searched quite a bit before asking this question, but I may be searching / asking the wrong question:*

I want to select the last two classes of an element (that has multiple classes and an unknown amount of classes) and store that in a variable. I then want to remove those two classes and add them back at a later point (like toggleClass). The first class is known, while the second class is unknown.

For instance:

```
<div class="c1 c2 c3 c-unknown"></div>
```

I would like to select `c3` and `c-unknown`

I've tried `split()` and it seems like the solution, but I couldn't quite get it to work.

I appreciate any help / guidance you can offer.

Comment: Have you looked at the .removeClass call? http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/ Im not sure I fully understand the requirement.

Comment: So, if you want to use a selector `$('.c3[class^="c-"], .c3[class*=" c-"]')`. But that's unreadable. Just not that if you remove the class, you will not be able to reselect it to re-add you class. You need to cache it.

Comment: @user2524908 I would like to select those last two classes `c-unknown` is unknown because it's dynamically created. I need to be able to select those two classes no matter what `c-unknown` ends up becoming.

@rafaeldefazio `c-unknown` is an unknown class. It will be dynamically created so I won't have the class name. This is not a duplicate to the question you posted.

Comment: Thanks @Karl-AndréGagnon. I should have clarified further, `c-unknown` could be any class name regardless of case or characters (although no symbols or numbers)

Comment: @shooghkirk So... what is the *rule* for the unknown class? How can you know which class is unknown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store them on the element itself allowing to isolate multiple instances

Following solution doesn't need classes to be in any specific order or matter how many classes are on element.

```
$('.c1').each(function () {
    /* array of classes on elemnt*/
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    /* remove the targeted selector from array */
    classes.splice(classes.indexOf('c1'), 1);
    /* remove the extra classes from element and store */
    $(this).removeClass(classes.join(' ')).data('classes', classes);

});
```

For a specific element could also use `attr(function)`

```
 $('.c1.Specific').attr('class', function(_, existingClasses){      
        var classes = existingClasses.split(' ');        
        classes.splice(classes.indexOf('c1', 1));
        $(this).data('classes', classes);
        return 'c1';
 });
```

Then to re-use the stored classes

```
var $el = $('.c1:first');
$el.addClass( $el.data('classes').join(' '))
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0hf6cjLd/)**</kbd>

Comment: You've given me some homework on this one. It looks pretty good. Let me try that out and get back to you. I really appreciate it.

Comment: found a syntax error while creating demo, added demo link

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to get the last two classes:

```
var lastTwoClasses = $('.c1').attr('class').split(/\s+/).slice(-2).join(' ');
```

Toggle (for example with button `id="btn"`):

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('.c1').toggleClass(lastTwoClasses); 
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/kw35p3uh/6/)**

---

**EDIT**.
And yet another way:

```
$('.c1').each(function(){
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/).slice(-2).join(' ');
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass(classes);  
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/kw35p3uh/5/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot Phillip! Works right out of the box. I appreciate it. If you don't mind, I have another question: What if you had multiple `.someDiv` with various last two classes? For example: `<div id="someDiv" class="c1 c2 c3 c4">Something</div>` and `<div id="someDiv" class="c1 c2 c3 c5">Something</div>` and `<div id="someDiv" class="c1 c2 c3 c6">Something</div>` etc. Here's my guess: Use `each()` to run through each of them storing them into their own unique variable and then check with `hasClass()` like your example? Bear with me if this is elementary stuff!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're trying to do.

```
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('c1'),
    classes = ele[0].className,
    classArr = classes.split(' '),
    spliceIndex = classArr.length - 2,
    last2Classes = classArr.splice(spliceIndex, 2);
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xw9Lh990/1/)

If you're trying to remove the classes you can use jquery or you could just use the dom element's className property and set it to whichever array has the classes you want to use. You would use the array method .toString() on either array and it will give you a string representation of the classes.

Comment: Doug, this looks awesome. Again, more homework for me. I don't see how this couldn't work, but let me get back to you on it. I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you have any questions feel free to ask. I can explain any part that looks confusing. I just tried to build what you described above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here could help you to get part of the functionality you need:
[Get first and last class with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872476/get-first-and-last-class-with-jquery)

Starting with that, you could use split, and removeClass like this
(sample text and css added for demo purposes):

```js
function removeTheClasses(el) {
  var classes = el.attr("class").split(/\s/);
  
  var second_to_last = classes[classes.length - 2]; //second to last class
  var last = classes[classes.length -1]; //last class
  
  el.removeClass(second_to_last, last);
}

$('button').click(function() {
  removeTheClasses($('.c1'));  
});
```

```css
.c-unknown {font-weight:bold}
.c3 {color:pink}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="c1 c2 c3 c-unknown">
  ABC
</div>
<br/>
<button>Remove the last two classes</button>
```

In order to add these same classes back in (toggling), you'd have to keep a record of the recently removed classes. This would require:

1. pushing the values of the `first` & `last` variables to a cookie or web storage (if handling multiple elements at a time), OR
2. a single javascript variable above the scope of the 'removeTheClasses' function (if you're just handling one element at a time).

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for taking the time to help me out. I've got some HW to do to make sure I get this right and check your method and how it'll work with what I have.